# How to turn string into readable by php server way? (C#)

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I know that my server on real form submit turns `%CE%EB%E5%E3+%DF%EA%F3%F8%EA%E8%ED` into `Олег Якушкин` . How to peform string transfer from  `Олег Якушкин` into  `%CE%EB%E5%E3+%DF%EA%F3%F8%EA%E8%ED` using C#?

Comment: If it's any help searching in the library, the process is called "urlencoding" or "percent encoding". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urlencoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(str)
```

Note that this will encode a space character as %20, not +. However, PHP should handle that fine.

Comment: And BTW what is result encoding of such operation - UTF-8 (I work with russian and other such lancuages)?

Comment: [Yes, UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)